# Trouble with form controls in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following component and html template to display a form. It throws this error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined in [signUpForm.controls['email'] in SignupComponent@20:35]

Not sure what I need to do to access the `touched` feature? This code has worked elsewhere, so not sure what I need to do to get it to work?

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Control } from 'angular2/common';

import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup',
  templateUrl: 'client/dev/user/templates/signup.html',
  styleUrls: ['client/dev/user/styles/user.css'],
  providers: []
})

export class SignupComponent {
    title: string = "Sign Up";
    signupForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor( @Inject(FormBuilder) fb:FormBuilder, @Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router) {
    this.signupForm = fb.group({
      "firstName": ["", Validators.required],
      "lastName": ["", Validators.required],
      "email": ["", Validators.required],
      "password": ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
  onSubmit(details):void {
    console.log("on Submit here");
    this._userService.signUp(details)
    .subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        console.log("Link to Todo?");
        this._router.navigate(['LoginComponent']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

signup.html:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="signUp-email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="signUpForm.controls['email']" #email="ngForm" class="form-control" id="signUp-email">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.control.hasError('required') && email.control.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.control.hasError('email') && email.control.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is invalid
        </div>
```

update:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="signUp-email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="signUpForm?.controls['email']" #email="ngForm" class="form-control" id="signUp-email">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.control.hasError('required') && email.control.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.control.hasError('email') && email.control.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is invalid
        </div>
```

Comment: `signUpForm?.controls['email']`, the same with the others, they will throw the same error message.

Comment: and also change `signupForm` to `signUpForm` in your `.ts`

Comment: @EricMartinez is the question update what you meant? It still doesn't work...

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards yes, that's what I meant. You also have to do what A_Singh suggested, the property doesn't match the name in the template.

Comment: Is it working now?